# JDBC Malformed Unicode Exception

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I am trying to store a encoded google maps route in my Postgres database. When I do this with my servlet with JDBC I get the following exception. This happens when the API tries to parse the string that I insert. However, when I directly insert the value to the database table it works without complaints.

```
   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid Unicode escape
      Hint: Unicode escapes must be \uXXXX or \UXXXXXXXX.
      Position: 123
```

A section of the value for which this exception is thrown is:

```
}ofi@ukkfNzFuB`Aa@fCkAh@YbAu@rB}Ap@_@t@Wx@Qt@Er@Cx@BnHn@NAR?LCJIJQMsBGe@KYgAyBOu@?OBKHI`@QhA?pAC~@ILE\\QHGHMFs@VqQOkD@_JEu@IKCSFSJIDAH_@DuGByAB[BKFG@F@ROxJ?^FNBDFNCTKLODUEIICG?UJQHEHYDaEDsDDa@HMD_E@kBD}HRcQFuHH{DCGAwA@yBPwRJuHNsAJ_BHcL@mIHmFH{@Po@LWRS~DsCe@eAMOEIMEq@GiBLEoAOkBC{@IoADWn@{AlBr@mBs@H[D_AOwBCk@@s@Je@?OBQl@qBdA{DjAqELUX]LKZSCKGWAICy@NgAX}@|@kB`CmEjCcFnAaD`@mAV}@`@iBp@eE\\uCPaAf@}Ah@gAbAuA`@c@vAsApF{El@q
```

Comment: Why would you need a value of such a syntax? Why not use something like base-64?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This happens when the API tries to parse the string that I insert.

I think you mean it happens when it tries to parse the SQL that you concatenate the string into, don't you?

Use a `PreparedStatement`, and use it properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used PreparedStatement earlier. However, I was not using it correctly. Now the value saves fine.

Answer (score 2):

One may prepare parameterized statements with [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)s in such cases.

Using statement parameters would avoid:

- problems with special characters
- and thus, also SQL injection

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification and enlightening me on PreparedStatements value on handling special characters.

Answer (score -1):

JDBC is interpreting this section of the String `\uCPaAf` as an attempt at putting in unicode. You need to double escape the preceding `\\` so that it becomes `\\\\uCPaAf`